# Выборка максимальной даты из двух таблиц с одинаковой структурой

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Даны две таблицы с одинаковой структурой:

Таблица 1 - Приём наличных:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cashreceiving` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idaccount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dateop` date NOT NULL,
  `timeop` time NOT NULL,
  `accepted` double NOT NULL,
  `monebalance` double NOT NULL,
  `moneytype` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

Таблица 2 - Выдача наличных:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cashwithdrawal` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idaccount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dateop` date NOT NULL,
  `timeop` time NOT NULL,
  `accepted` double NOT NULL,
  `monebalance` double NOT NULL,
  `moneytype` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Необходимо найти остаток на счете (monebalance) исходя из максимальной даты (dateop) и времени (timeop) в обоих таблицах.

Запрос на одну таблицу примерно следующий:

```
SELECT 
`cashreceiving`.`idaccount` ,
MAX(  `cashreceiving`.`dateop` ) ,
MAX(  `cashreceiving`.`timeop` ) ,
MAX(  `cashreceiving`.`monebalance` ) AS maxmoney
FROM  `cashreceiving` 
WHERE  `cashreceiving`.`idaccount` =1
```

Где idaccount - это имя счета.

Comment: Т.е. вам нужен monebalance из записи с максимальной датой/временем, причем из той таблицы, где дата/время у такой записи больше, чем в другой таблице ? И кстати, ваш запрос выбирает просто максимальный баланс из всех записей, а не из записи с максимальной датой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то одна запись с максимальной датой/временем из двух таблиц может быть выбрана так:

```
select idaccount,dateop,timeop,monebalance
  from
 (
    select * from (
      select * from cashreceiving
       where idaccount=1
       order by dateop desc,timeop desc
       limit 1
    ) A
   union
    select * from (
      select * from cashwithdrawal
       where idaccount=1
       order by dateop desc,timeop desc
       limit 1
    ) B
 ) C
order by dateop desc,timeop desc
limit 1
```

А вообще с такой структурой таблиц, готовьтесь возмещать убытки клиентам или заказчикам. Во первых, `double` это число с плавающей точкой, в нем точность числа не гарантирована. Т.е. деньги в нем в принципе хранить нельзя. Используйте `decimal` или в копейках храните в целочисленных полях (int). Во вторых, хранение текущего баланса в виде числа, которое ищется по максимальным датам в двух таблицах очень спорное решение. Мне даже сложно представить, какая у вас логика в приложении будет накручена, что бы этот баланс правильно вычислять. И если при такой логике не следить или не правильно следить за транзакциями и блокировками, то будет масса проблем с одновременной модификацией одних и тех же данных. В конечном счете код, который будет обеспечивать данную логику потенциально будет содержать ошибки, ведущие к неправильным вычислениям баланса.

Наиболее надежным способом хранения денежных операций является *одна* таблица со всеми операциями по счету, причем только со значениями конкретной текущей операции, `+` или `-` в ней разумеется должен быть "вид транзакции" по которому можно будет понять, что это за операция. Со временем кроме просто "поступления" и "списания" может появится масса разновидностей начислений/списаний. Так же к транзакции можно хранить id-ссылки на первичные документы, на основании которых прошли операции (если нужны), хранящиеся в своих таблицах, со своей спецификой для конкретных операций. И самое главное - текущий баланс аккаунта по такой таблице получается как абсолютная сумма всех операций в таблице по данному id аккаунта. Вычислить неправильно невозможно. Не учесть совместный доступ так же практически нереально, т.к. записи просто добавляются и никогда не модифицируются. Единственное, может со временем появится отправка записей в архив, с выведением начального сальдо и внесением его в эту таблицу одной записью. Ну тут надо будет просто аккуратно в одной транзакции реализовать.

И кстати в mysql есть замечательный тип данных `datetime` позволяющий хранить дату/время в одной колонке.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ и вразумительные комментарии к нему!